# Setting up path in the below code

Tags: php

```
<?php

    if($_FILES['Filedata']['size']>=520000)
    {
        echo "\n Sorry, Not Moved Size below 5.2kb or 5200 bytes Only\n";
        return;
    }
    $ext = end(explode('.', strtolower($_FILES['Filedata']['name'])));

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'], "./".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']))
    {
        echo "\nfile moved Success\n";
        return;
    }
?>
```

When i set path, it does not work... i dont know where to exactly set path such that the file gets saved in the directory.

Comment: I'd appreciate some extra information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [`move_uploaded_file`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) documentation.

The first argument (`$_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name']`) is the source, which you shouldn't change. The second argument (`"./".$_FILES['Filedata']['name']`) is the destination, which will currently put the file in the current working directory with its original name (This can be a security issue; you should put the file in an upload directory that has no execute permissions.)